# Pug CLI - Compile template to exportable js function

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm trying to use Pug as a templating engine for sending transactional emails. I want to compile them during the build step, then just require/import the function in my code (to avoid compiling online).

I'm using the Pug CLI to compile the templates.

`pug ./src/emails/pug --client --pretty --no-debug --out ./src/emails/tpl`

This creates `.js` files in the out directory that look like this.

```
function pug_escape(e) {
    var a = "" + e,
        t = pug_match_html.exec(a);
    if (!t) return e;
    var r, c, n, s = "";
    for (r = t.index, c = 0; r < a.length; r++) {
        switch (a.charCodeAt(r)) {
            case 34:
                n = "&quot;";
                break;
            case 38:
                n = "&amp;";
                break;
            case 60:
                n = "&lt;";
                break;
            case 62:
                n = "&gt;";
                break;
            default:
                continue
        }
        c !== r && (s += a.substring(c, r)), c = r + 1, s += n
    }
    return c !== r ? s + a.substring(c, r) : s
}
var pug_match_html = /["&<>]/;

function template(locals) {
    var pug_html = "",
        pug_mixins = {},
        pug_interp;;
    var locals_for_with = (locals || {});
    (function(emailTo) {
        var pug_indent = [];
        pug_html = pug_html + "\u003Ch1\u003EYou sent money to " + (pug_escape(null == (pug_interp = emailTo) ? "" : pug_interp)) + "\u003C\u002Fh1\u003E";
    }.call(this, "emailTo" in locals_for_with ? locals_for_with.emailTo : typeof emailTo !== "undefined" ? emailTo : undefined));;
    return pug_html;
}
```

How can I import this function as a module so that I might be able to use it like this?

```
import sendEmail from './tpl/email'
sendEmail(data)
```

Is it possible, or am I missing something about how I'm supposed to compile and use functions?

Answer (score 0):

I happen to be using webpack and just found the pug-loader, which does what I need (loads a .pug file as a function).

I'll leave this open for now in case someone has a non-webpack answer that I can mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching around this lot, because I liked how [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) works, just don't like the clearance compared to Pug. Client side rendering can be also achieved using [Puglatizer](https://github.com/happilymarrieddad/puglatizer), however, it is somehow dead.